# When rendering animation in Mpeg 4 with H.264 codec, the final product looks like garbage

Tags: animation

Rendering an animation with the video sequencer and using the H.264 codec with Mpeg 4 makes my animation look ugly. I've tried a few other codecs but they compress the hell out of the image. Am I supposed to pair the Mpeg 4 container with a different codec?

Images:

[image: Looks fine in the render preview...]

[image: But is unrecognisable when playing back the final Mpeg 4]

I added captions to the images, but the top one is what I see in the render preview and the bottom one is what I see when I play the final Mpeg 4 file

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about Blender, but rather VLC media player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out guys. Turns out that I'm just stupid and VLC media player doesn't have h.264 codec turned on by default or something.
The video plays fine when imported into lightworks so problem solved, yeah baby